# Why is a Ruby class allowing access to an instance variable through a return from a method?

Tags: ruby, reference, encapsulation, instance-variables

I have this Ruby code from a colleague:

```
class Leaky

   def initialize
      @internalOnly = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
   end

   def foo
      if 5 > 4
         temp = @internalOnly
      end
   end

   def printInternal
      puts " here is my @internalOnly: #{@internalOnly}"
   end

end

a = Leaky.new
a.printInternal

b = a.foo  # 1) Gets Leaky:@internal!
b[1] = 666 # 2) Modifies it!

a.printInternal
```

It produces this output:

```
 here is my @internalOnly: [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
 here is my @internalOnly: [[1, 2, 3], 666]
```

In statement `# 1)`, Ruby is apparently returning a reference to the `Leaky` instance variable `@internalOnly`, which it then uses to modify `@internalOnly` in statement `#2)`.

When `Leaky:printInternal` is called, the (externally) modified value is displayed.

I understand that

1. Variables are references in Ruby, so `temp = @internalOnly` in the `Leaky:foo` method assigns a reference to `@internalOnly`
2. Ruby returns the value of this expression -- the Array assigned to `@internalOnly`

After that, I don't understand how `b = a.foo` ends up with a reference to `@internalOnly`; this would seem to violate Ruby's object encapsulation in a big way. What is going on here?

I couldn't find anything in the [Ruby Language FAQ](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/FAQ/FAQ.html) that would enlighten me. (Maybe this is an *inFAQ*...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) foo() is just an accessor method with a strange name, no different than:

```
def internalOnly
  @internalOnly
end
```

2) Any method in a class can access the private variables of an instance, i.e. its @variables.

3) Methods return the 'value' of the last statement executed.

4) The value of an assignment statement is the right hand side.

> After that, I don't understand how b = a.foo ends up with a reference
>   to @internalOnly
>
> Variables are references in Ruby

Because a.foo returns a reference to the array, which gets assigned to b.  As a result, the two variables @internalOnly and b reference the same array.

> this would seem to violate Ruby's object encapsulation in a big way.
>   What is going on here?

Well, the programmer allowed that to happen.  If that wasn't intended, then the code can be rewritten like this:

```
   def foo
      if 5 > 4
         @internalOnly.dup
      end
   end
```

But, you should know that any programmer with enough knowledge of ruby can always access an instance's private variables:

```
class Dog
  attr_reader :friends

  def initialize(friends)
    @friends = friends
  end
end

d = Dog.new(['cat', 'bird', 'mouse'])

x = d.instance_variable_get(:@friends)
x[0] = 'velociraptor'

p d.friends

--output:--
["velociraptor", "bird", "mouse"]
```

Comment: Good answer, VII, but please clarify what you mean by "private variables", considering that there are local variables and instance variables, and some of the latter have accessors and some don't.

Comment: Nice, complete answer. Thanks.